# Missing a feature after digitalization of a geopackage vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I am trying for the first time the geopackage format and I am facing a weird behavior, for me at least.

I hade a file with two polygon features and I have added a third one by digitatizing. After editing I can see the third feature in the attribute table but not in the canvas. Performing a `check validity` returns a layer called *valid_output* with the three features.

What could it be wrong?

Here the link of the file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09465121551351065440

I also see a "[3]" in the layer name that puzzels me.
[image]

What is it?

Comment: Ok. the [3] is the "feature count"

Comment: do you have the projection of the data and canvas the same?

Comment: @IanTurton, yes, everything in UTM EPSG 3006). I have just realized that when I zoom out (just above 1:10,000), I see the missing feature, a problem I do not have for the layer *valid_output*.

Comment: Does the layer have a scale-based style?

Comment: No, nothing special in style, rendering or any other of the properties

Comment: Dumb suggestion but: Have you tried reloading QGIS? Did it work then?

Comment: @bugmenot123, :) yes, over a couple of days. The error in the display persists

Comment: Hm, can you share the file?

Comment: @bugmenot123, done, there the link. I gave up with the use of it this format time, but I am looking forward to getting rid of .shp files

Comment: Interesting, the third line disappears for me if the north-most line touches the top of the canvas.

Comment: @bugmenot123 it is a bug of something, but what kind? I would be happy to report it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but this looks a bug to me. I created an issue for it:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17867 and added the data

Looks like it is something with the actual geopackage, as saving as geojson and viewing it in geojson.io is fine, also as shapefile it behaves normal in QGIS

Comment: Not a solution, but you did it right by reportining it properly